# Timestamp and Blameable Behavior - C# Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Okay, I just started using WebAPI.

I have always used YII and most recently YII2, which has two good behaviors , [the timestamp](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html) and  [the Blameable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-blameablebehavior.html)
The timestamp basically auto fills the `created_at` and `updated_at` on record creating and update while the Blameable auto fills `created_by` and `updated_by` fields, to indicate who last manipulated a record.

Is there a similar implementation of these in C# or if not, what is the best approach to add this kind of logic to my application.

I don't want to use database triggers.

Comment: Presumably, the second instances of `created_at` and `updated_at` in your question should actually be, say, `created_by` and `updated_by`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you for the correction..i have edited the question to reflect that